# How can parse DateTime in web service method

Tags: c#, json, datetime

I have build a web service with web api in c#.

I have created a method to retrieve some record from database. One column of it, is datetime. I want format it.

So I have this method to retrieve the records from database:

```
[NonAction]
private IQueryable<WSOmniacare.Models.AAHome.ImmaginiSecSoc.ImmaginiSecSocDTO> getSecSocImages(int? id)
{
   var strItem = from u in db_data.CAMERA_SEC_SOC
          where u.ID == id
          select u.Image;

    String imageBas64 = GetString(strItem.First());

    if (id != null)
    {
    return from u in db_data.CAMERA_SEC_SOC 
           where u.ID == id
           select new WSOmniacare.Models.AAHome.ImmaginiSecSoc.ImmaginiSecSocDTO()
           {
           image = imageBas64,
           image_width = u.image_width,
           image_height= u.image_height,
           type = u.type,
           timestamp =u.timestamp.ToString(),
           dateTime = u.timestamp,
           rectangle = new WSOmniacare.Models.AAHome.ImmaginiSecSoc.ImmaginiSecSocDTO.Rectangle()
           {
             rects = from pi in db_data.CAMERA_SEC_SOC_Rectangles 
                where pi.ID_SecSoc  == id
                 select new WSOmniacare.Models.AAHome.ImmaginiSecSoc.ImmaginiSecSocDTO.Rectangle.Rect()
                {   
                height= pi.height,
                width = pi.width,
                x = pi.x,
                y=pi.y
                }
           } 
           };
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is the method to create a response:

```
public HttpResponseMessage getSecSocData(int? id = null)
{
    try
    {
    IQueryable<ImmaginiSecSoc.ImmaginiSecSocDTO> lista = getSecSocImages(id);
    List<ImmaginiSecSoc.ImmaginiSecSocDTO> listaModificata = new List<ImmaginiSecSoc.ImmaginiSecSocDTO>();
    foreach (ImmaginiSecSoc.ImmaginiSecSocDTO a in lista)
    {
        a.timestamp = a.dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff");
        listaModificata.Add(a);
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new RCamera((short)status_code.Success, "Ok", listaModificata));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    e = e.GetBaseException();
    log.Error(string.Format("{0} {1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace));
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new RMessage((short)status_code.Exception, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError.ToString()));
    }
}
```

As you can see, I must cycle the list and formatting the field timestamp. 
Now my question is, how can I change the code o the parse JSON to formatting my date?

Answer (score 0):

You're already doing

```
timestamp =u.timestamp.ToString(),
```

in `getSecSocImages` method,

If the format is always the same, change it to

```
timestamp =u.timestamp.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"),
```

Comment: I have just use this code, but not works because the method toString is not supported from Entity Framework